# Gradle property as a string?

Tags: android, gradle, groovy, build.gradle

I am trying to set up ENV vars in my Android application (e.g. API keys for different environments). The command in our CICD that builds the apk file is found below (it can be release or debug but for the example below I am using debug)

```
gradlew assembleDebug
```

This works just fine, but now throughout the code I am using variables similar to the code snippet below:

```
private static final String API_KEY = BuildConfig.apiKey;
```

The idea is that the `BuildConfig` property `apiKey` would be replaced with different API keys based off of the env. My thought was to set the properties through the following command:

```
gradlew assembleDebug -PapiKey=SOME_STRING_API_KEY_VALUE
```

This does assign apiKey to the value SOME_STRING_API_KEY_VALUE  but as a variable and not a string. I just want the string value. I feel there is some aspect of gradle/groovy that I am not understanding but what I want to accomplish seems pretty trivial.

Comment: Are you trying to use Gradle properties in your app, or use them to build the app?

Comment: I am trying to use the values in my app. It is just those values will change depending on the environment it is in. I am using AWS to store keys for different stages (dev, qa, prod, etc). Currently I am passing those keys via the command as a property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for the inconvenience I should have done a little more research. I just had to use the escape characters for the API key values `-PapiKey=\“SOME_STRING_API_KEY_VALUE\”` if there is a more elegant solution to what I am trying to accomplish please let me know!